# Getting No Feature Found Exception in Cucumber Test with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm new to cucumber. when i'm trying to run the feature files separately i'm getting no Feature found Exception. i tried all the suggestions from the already asked questions in StackOverflow but those are not worked for me. please help me to solve this issue.

**My Feature File**

```
Feature: CucumberJava

  Scenario: Logging in to Facebook using DataTables
    Given I have open the "Chrome" browser
    When I open Facebook website
    And Logging in to Facebook using DataTables
      | Feild               | Values              |
      | Email id            | fsferr@dsgs.com     |
      | Password            | dvfsgg              |
    Then Click on Login button
```

**My Runner file**

```
package cucumberPackage;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
//@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 
@Cucumber.Options(features="src/test/resources/demo/DataTables.feature",format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 
public class RunnerTest {

}
```

**Error Log**

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at [src/test/resources/demo/DataTables.feature]
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:82)
    at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Could you please post the directory structure and name for the files in your question and how do you start the test.

Comment: Directory structure means project explorer structure? and i didnt get what you asked regarding the Name for the files

Comment: Only with your posted snippets it's hard to guess where the issue might be. Therefor it would be helpful to know the name of your feature file and it's location on the file system. My guess is that your feature file is either not named   `DataTables.feature` or is not located in `src/test/resources/demo/`. If you believe this cannot be the reason for your problem, then post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which allows everybody to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added an example which shows that it should work (after taking few assumptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following assumption is made

- you are using Cucumber version <= 1.1.8 (because of your use of `@Cucumber.Options`, which has been removed in version 1.2.0, the current Cucumber release is [3.0.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java), maybe think about updating to a recent version
- the following files exists in the current directory

  ```
  src/test/java/cucumberPackage/RunnerTest.java
  src/test/resources/demo/DataTables.feature
  pom.xml
  ```

**RunnerTest.java**

as in your post, with fixed import statement for `Cucumber.class`

```
// import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
```

**DataTables.feature**

as in your post

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suboptimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cuke-test.so</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <version.cucumber>1.1.8</version.cucumber>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

running the test with `mvn test` executes you scenario

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running cucumberPackage.RunnerTest
Feature: CucumberJava

  Scenario: Logging in to Facebook using DataTables # src/test/resources/demo/DataTables.feature:3
    Given I have open the "Chrome" browser
    When I open Facebook website
    And Logging in to Facebook using DataTables
    Then Click on Login button

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
...
```

Comment: Thank you.. it worked for me. i updated my cucumber version